# IKE Initiator unable to find policy: Intf inside

Tags: cisco, pix

I'm trying to setup a site to site vpn but am seeing the following error in the logs.  My device is a PIX 515e.

Error:

```
%PIX-3-713042: IKE Initiator unable to find policy: Intf inside, Src: 10.1.1.4, Dst: 172.17.105.153
```

Config is:

```
interface Ethernet0
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 1.1.1.204 255.255.255.248 
!
interface Ethernet1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
ftp mode passive
access-list 115 extended permit ip host 10.1.1.4 host 172.17.105.153 
access-list 115 extended deny ip 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0 any
access-list outbound extended permit ip any any 
access-list 120 extended permit ip host 10.1.1.4 host 172.17.105.153 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging buffer-size 500000
logging console debugging
logging buffered debugging
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
no failover
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 1.1.1.205
nat (inside) 0 access-list 120
access-group OUTSIDE in interface outside
access-group outbound in interface inside
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 1.1.1.203 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 3600
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
crypto dynamic-map DYNMAP100 10 match address 115
crypto dynamic-map DYNMAP100 10 set peer y.y.y.2 
crypto dynamic-map DYNMAP100 10 set transform-set ESP-AES128-SHA
crypto dynamic-map DYNMAP100 10 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
crypto map outside 60000 ipsec-isakmp dynamic DYNMAP100
crypto map outside interface outside
crypto isakmp identity address 
crypto isakmp enable outside
crypto isakmp policy 100
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 60
ssh version 2
console timeout 0
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *
tunnel-group y.y.y.2 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group y.y.y.2 ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect http 
  inspect ipsec-pass-thru 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
Cryptochecksum:e65d9e3f55afd168aa7cbb7016015071
: end
```

If I try to ping the remote ip ending in .153, I get a response timed out, the tunnel never comes up and I get the error shown above in the config.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the second line in access list 115.  It doesn't do anything anyway.  If that doesn't work, please post the config from the other end.